# Logistic Regression in R: Confidence interval for a x value (predictor) for a particular y value (outcome)

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, predict

I fit a logistic regression model to data to predict success or failure of a medical test based on age. I found the ages associated with different probabilities of failure by solving for age with the parameters from the model.

```
fun2 <- function(prob, b0, b1){
  goalx <- (log(prob/(1-prob)) - b0)/b1
}

prob <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)
b0 <- coef(logit2)[1]
b1 <- coef(logit2)[2]

newx <- mapply(fun2, prob, b0, b1)
```

How would I find a confidence interval for these age values? For example, the 95% CI for age associated with p(success) = 0.5? Do I just use the confidence intervals for the parameters?

Comment: One can use the `predict()` function to calculate the confidence intervals.

Comment: I think that's more of a statistical question than a programming question.  The idea is to think of the value you're looking for as a function of the parameters of the model.  You know joint confidence regions for the parameters, so you can convert those into confidence intervals for that function of them.

Comment: @Dave2e, I don't think `predict()` can do that.  For fixed `x` it can give intervals for the response probability, but it doesn't do the inverse problem, which is what laura needs.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/551416/274489 .